# Facebook SDK integration in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, facebook

I have wpf desktop application and I want Facebook login integration in this application so that users can share images from local machine, moreover I am using "Facebook.7.0.6" sdk. Apparently I am facing following issue on login screen.

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

And below coding I am using in my application.

```
  private Uri GenerateLoginUrl(string appId, string extendedPermissions)
    {
        // for .net 3.5
        // var parameters = new Dictionary<string,object>
        // parameters["client_id"] = appId;
        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.client_id = appId;
        parameters.redirect_uri = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";

        // The requested response: an access token (token), an authorization code (code), or both (code token).
        parameters.response_type = "token";

        // list of additional display modes can be found at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/#display
        parameters.display = "popup";

        // add the 'scope' parameter only if we have extendedPermissions.
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(extendedPermissions))
            parameters.scope = extendedPermissions;

        // generate the login url
        var fb = new FacebookClient();
        return fb.GetLoginUrl(parameters);
    }



void facebookBrowser_Navigated(Object sender,NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var fb = new FacebookClient();
        FacebookOAuthResult oauthResult;
        if (!fb.TryParseOAuthCallbackUrl(e.Uri, out oauthResult))
            return;
        if (oauthResult.IsSuccess)
            LoginSucceeded(oauthResult);

    }
```

*Note : Let me know if Facebook have any change in term and condition for desktop application.*

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

After some study I got this link and now my application working fine.

Please set below settings on Facebook app first.

Native or desktop app? - Yes
Client OAuth login - Yes
Embedded browser OAuth Login - Yes

read more from this link :-https://www.hackviking.com/2014/11/facebook-api-login-flow-for-desktop-application/

Thanks

Comment: Thanks. Works for me to, finally.

Answer (score 0):

This error means you haven't configured well you app on [facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/)
If you are testing on localhost, you need to add a platform to your app, then configuring the "site url" for the example http://localhost. Then create a test app (a copy of your main app) and use it for your tests.

Comment: I have wpf desktop application and I want Facebook login integration in this application so that users can share images from local machine, moreover I am using "Facebook.7.0.6" sdk. Apparently I am facing following issue on login screen. I am not developing web application.

Comment: You do need to register an application on facebook if you want to be able to have contact with facebook api services. Whatever you do, if you want to use facebook api feature, you need to create an app on facebook site. I'm not talking about a page or anything, but you will need this app to make your authentifications and other calls.

Comment: I have already created application on Facebook and I have "Application ID" and "App secret" so on.